# Won't let me push to heroku

Tags: heroku

I have simple html, css and javascript and I can't seem to push to Heroku.  Not sure what the problem is.  Below is the error I'm getting.

```
Counting objects: 75, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (72/72), done.
Writing objects: 100% (75/75), 879.94 KiB | 20.46 MiB/s, done.
Total 75 (delta 33), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect       the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
 remote:  !     Push failed
 remote: Verifying deploy...
 remote:
 remote: !       Push rejected to brians-rock-paper-scissors.
 remote:
  To https://git.heroku.com/brians-rock-paper-scissors.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/brians-rock-paper-   scissors.git'
```

Having looked in the docs for build pack I can't seem to see anything that helps me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow all steps from Heroku documentation.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/start

First, choose your technology then follow it will help you.

Comment: Suppose it is none of these?  It is just an html, css and javascript app.

Comment: Heroku is the server and we have to use these technology